# Printing integers up to 1000 and are not multiples of 5

Tags: assembly

How can I shorten this?

```
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69
.equ SWI_PrInt, 0x6b
.equ StDout, 1
.equ SWI_EXIT, 0x11

.global _start
start:

MOV R5, #1
MOV R6, #1
MOV R7, #1000

LOOPHERE:

CMP R5, R7
BLE LOOPBODY
B LOOPDONE

LOOPBODY:

CMP R6, #5
BLT LOOPIF
MOV R6, #0
B LOOPNEXT

LOOPIF:

MOV R0, #StDout
MOV R1, R5
swi SWI_PrInt

ldr R1, =EOL
swi SWI_PrStr

B LOOPNEXT

LOOPNEXT:

ADD R5, R5, #1
ADD R6, R6, #1
B LOOPHERE

LOOPDONE:
swi SWI_EXIT

.data

EOL: .asciz "\n"
.end
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of jumping over a jump:

```
BLE LOOPBODY
B LOOPDONE
LOOPBODY:
```

you can just invert the condition and jump directly:

```
BGT LOOPDONE
```

However, as the first iteration will always happen, you can just put the check at the end of the loop instead:

```
LOOPHERE:

... the code in the loop

CMP R5, R7
BLE LOOPHERE
```

The jump to `LOOPNEXT` right before the label can be skipped:

```
B LOOPNEXT

LOOPNEXT:
```

So:

```
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69
.equ SWI_PrInt, 0x6b
.equ StDout, 1
.equ SWI_EXIT, 0x11

.global _start
start:

MOV R5, #1
MOV R6, #1
MOV R7, #1000

LOOPHERE:

CMP R6, #5
BLT LOOPIF
MOV R6, #0
B LOOPNEXT

LOOPIF:

MOV R0, #StDout
MOV R1, R5
swi SWI_PrInt

ldr R1, =EOL
swi SWI_PrStr

LOOPNEXT:

ADD R5, R5, #1
ADD R6, R6, #1

CMP R5, R7
BLE LOOPHERE

swi SWI_EXIT

.data

EOL: .asciz "\n"
.end
```

Answer (score 3):

In assembly, you usually want to test conditions towards the end of the loop. I cannot explain why, but that generally holds true. In your case, the core of the code should look like

```
LOOP:
    print
    ADD R_value, R_value, #1
    ADD R_remainder, R_remainder, #1
    CMP R_remainder, #5
    BNE TEST
    MOV R_remainder, #0
TEST:
    CMP R_value, R_limit
    BLT LOOP
```

It would also be nice to know which machine you are running at. Typically you may spare one more instruction (namely, CMP R_remainder, #5) by *decrementing* remainder instead of incrementing it:

```
    SUB R_remainder, R_remainder, #1
    BNZ TEST
```

if the subtract instruction sets the Z flag (which it typically does).

Notice that even in the assembler you still may (and shall) use meaningful names.